# UITableView subclass with default style grouped

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have no clue how can I set grouped style as default to UITableView subclass. My goal is to get grouped TableView (ofc) but by something like that.

`TableSubclass *myView = (TableSubclass*)some.other.view`

Is this possible? I will be greatful for any advice.

### UPDATE

I have ios 6 app with custom UITabBar and custom more section.

My "custom" code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    firstUse=true;
    UINavigationController *moreController = self.moreNavigationController;
    moreController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;

    self.moreNavigationController.delegate = self;

    if ([moreController.topViewController.view isKindOfClass:[UITableView class]])
    {

         UITableView *view = (UITableView *)moreController.topViewController.view;
        view = [view initWithFrame:view.frame style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
        UIView* bview = [[UIView alloc] init];
        bview.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        [view setBackgroundView:bview];

        moreTableViewDataSource = [[NXMoreTableViewDataSource alloc] initWithDataSource:view.dataSource];
        view.dataSource = moreTableViewDataSource;

    }
}
```

It's working great under 6 but under 7 UITableView don't respond but when I remove

`[view initWithFrame:view.frame style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];`

It respond again but I lose grouped style.

Comment: This is a cast, which will not change the grouped style of some.other.view. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Joel I update my question for better explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the table view is not yet configured?
from [UITableView Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

> When you create a UITableView instance you must specify a table style,
>   and this style cannot be changed

**Have a look how to create and configure** [UITableView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH6-SW10).

Generally you use `UITableViewController` and then in:

```
- (void)loadView
{
    UITableView *tableView =
     [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]
                                  style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    ...
}
```